# Group by and Count distinct words in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, distinct-values

By year and name, I am hoping to count the occurrence of words in a dataframe from imported from Excel which results will also be exported to Excel.

This is the sample code:

```
source = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['John', 'Mike', 'John','John'], 
                  'Year' : ['1999', '2000', '2000','2000'],
                  'Message' : [

'I Love You','Will Remember You','Love','I Love You]})
```

Excepted results are the following in a dataframe. Any ideas?

```
Year Name Message Count
1999 John I 1
1999 John love 1
1999 John you 1

2000 Mike Will 1 
2000 Mike Remember 1
2000 Mike You 1 
2000 John Love 2
2000 John I 1
2000 John You 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column `Message`, create `Serie` and add it to original `source`. Last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
#split column Message to new df, create Serie by stack
s = (source.Message.str.split(expand=True).stack())
#remove multiindex
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name= 'Message'
print(s)
0           I
0        Love
0         You
1        Will
1    Remember
1         You
2        Love
3           I
3        Love
3         You
Name: Message, dtype: object

#remove old column Message
source = source.drop(['Message'], axis=1)
#join Serie s to df source
df = (source.join(s))

#aggregate size
print (df.groupby(['Year', 'Name', 'Message']).size().reset_index(name='count'))
   Year  Name   Message  count
0  1999  John         I      1
1  1999  John      Love      1
2  1999  John       You      1
3  2000  John         I      1
4  2000  John      Love      2
5  2000  John       You      1
6  2000  Mike  Remember      1
7  2000  Mike      Will      1
8  2000  Mike       You      1
```

Comment: Thanks! I have never seen such a use for index until now. Will read up more =D